# Bias and Variance Decomposition to find an optimal tuning parameter - Population vs Empirical

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, regression

I have a question regarding to this bias and variance decomposition in The Elements of Statistical Learning. In chapter 7.2, it mentioned $\operatorname{Err}\left(x_0\right)=$

$$E\left[\left(Y-\hat{f}\left(x_0\right)\right)^2 \mid X=x_0\right]=\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2+\left[\mathrm{E} \hat{f}\left(x_0\right)-f\left(x_0\right)\right]^2+E\left[\hat{f}\left(x_0\right)-\mathrm{E} \hat{f}\left(x_0\right)\right]^2 =\sigma_{\varepsilon}^2+\operatorname{Bias}^2\left(\hat{f}\left(x_0\right)\right)+\operatorname{Var}\left(\hat{f}\left(x_0\right)\right)$$

While keep $x_0$ fixed, this can be viewed as a population level expected prediction error. Later when the textbook talks about how to choose an optimal parameter analytically (prepare for C_p, AIC, etc), it talks about estimating this expected prediction error using the training sample, but no bias and variance decomposition was done there.

I wonder if bias and variance decomposition is only some analysis worth talking about in the population level?

In this [Bias-Variance Decomposition in Ridge Linear Regression](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4780/2022fa/slides/Bias_Var_Ridge.pdf), the decomposition has been intensively discussed. At the end, one can naturally optimize the sum of squared bias and variance to get an optimal penalty parameter $\lambda$. However, as the author mentioned, the result relies on couple of unknown (true) quantities.

So far it seems like one can find a feasible optimal $\lambda$ by optimizing the estimated expected prediction error, but cannot find a feasible optimal $\lambda$ from the bias variance decomposition, which is an analysis done worth only on the population level. Is that correct?

Comment: If your primary aim is to minimise the sum or average of the squares of the prediction errors, then it seems a natural approach to try to address that directly (since you know the prediction from a model using a particular $\lambda$ and you know the actual value) rather than trying to estimate the bias and variance separately, neither of which you can find.